# Nginx uses an upstream name instead of an IP

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have an Nginx server. I have configured upstream. In the test environment under tests everything works well. But I just implemented this in production where there are more requests. I started catching 502 errors.

```
upstream ts_backends {
           server 10.40.0.11;
           server 10.40.0.17;
        }
```

```
location /ts/ {
                  proxy_pass http://ts_backends;
                  proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                  proxy_next_upstream_tries 3;
                }
```

In the logs I find that Nginx uses an upstream name instead of an IP.

```
[27/Sep/2023:11:09:26 +0000] : [13.706] {ts_backends} - {ts_backends}PORT80"POST /ts/maintain HTTP/1.1" 502 1
[27/Sep/2023:11:10:26 +0000] : [13.706] {ts_backends} - {10.40.0.17:80, ts_backends}PORT80"POST /ts/maintain HTTP/1.1" 502 1
```

Could you please help me fix this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the log format? Have you read about `proxy_set_header` defaults?